# Using Pandoc, how would I convert a docx file, to a file with a format suitable for the Azure Wiki?

Tags: azure, markdown, pandoc, wiki

I have been trying to convert some of my Word documentation into some files suitable for an Azure Wiki. However, I haven't had much luck yet. I have tried converting the docx file to several different markdown formats, but none of them are exactly suitable for Azure DevOps.

By not being suitable for Azure DevOps Wiki, I mean, they don't look as good as on Azure DevOps Wiki, as they do in the original word document.

Some formats that I have tried converting my file into:

```
-t gfm (GitHub-Flavored Markdown)  
-t markdown_mmd (MultiMarkdown)  
-t markdown (pandoc’s extended Markdown)  
-t markdown_strict (original unextended Markdown)  
-t markdown_phpextra (PHP Markdown Extra)  
-t commonmark (CommonMark Markdown)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your Word documents are simple, you won't get parity. Wiki does not offer the rich formatting of MS Word. In a way, that's part of Wiki's value. You won't spend time futzing with formatting (ideally).

I "took a run at" this about a year ago and came to the same conclusion. You really can't get there - reliably. Fortunately, my volume was low, and I was able transfer my docs manually (copy/paste and format in Wiki markdown).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327762/418950) to a different question explains it better.